# Cant push a folder on git

Tags: git

Hello Im new on gitlab so i want to push a folder on gitlab however i cant do the task because its give me some error
its says

> [Rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
> Error: failed to push some refs to '*[https://gitlab.com/sen-flutter.git*'](https://gitlab.com/sen-flutter.git*%27)
> Hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> Hint: Its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote change (e.g. 'git pull ...')
> before pushing again.
> Hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in git push --help' for details

I have try any tutorials on youtube but it didnt go very well
Hope someone fix it for me
Thanks before

Comment: The answer is in the git output. _"Hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind Hint: Its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote change (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again."_

Comment: i tried it to follow the hint on youtube before this error appear its shows git error fetch first and now this error appear

Comment: Fetch isn't enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: Git doesn't push folders; it doesn't even *store* folders. Git stores files inside commits, and `git push` pushes those *commits*. (The files may have names that cause another clone to create folders to store those files into, but they're just files.)

Comment: You should use `git pull origin master` and try to push again `git push origin master` to push a folder `git add folder_name/` and  `git commit -m "mesaage_name` and push to remote host

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, before continuing to work you need to run `git pull` in order to pull the latest remote changes to your local branch. Then you should be able to commit/push files to gitlab. However, you can't just commit/push an empty directory. You can only commit/push files so you will need to create a file in the directory and then commit/push that file in order to see the file and directory on gitlab.